# Creating multiple store functions in laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have created an appointments controller that has a store function, this is working perfectly.

Now my store function stores data for a few locations but now I need to seperate some logic and create an additional function that stores just an appointment.

When I create the function and add the route: -

```
Route::resource('appointments', 'AppointmentsController');
Route::post('appointments','AppointmentsController@storeAppointmentOnly')->name('storeAppointmentOnly');
```

The storeAppointmentOnly overrides the default store function (I can see this using php artisan route:list) is it possible to make both functions independent and not override one another?

Comment: dont have them using the same uri and method

Comment: I changed the post route to appointmentsOnly. Tested my form and It worked first time thank you!